# Мониторинг открытых файлов через Zabbix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zabbix

Появилась нужда в мониторинге количества открытых файлов на сервере.

Решение было найдено через `lsof`. После двух дней работы сервер «захлебнулся». Слишком тяжкое это дело.

Чем ещё можно мониторить?

Comment: а зачем могут понадобиться **имена** «открытых» файлов? видимо, перед вами стоит какая-то глобальная задача, которую вы не озвучили.

Comment: задача стоит мониторить количество открытых файлов.

Comment: sysctl fs.file-nr попробуйте. Первое число - количество открытых файлов.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, у меня в ответе именно этот совет и приведён. только без запуска дополнительной программы-обёртки.

Comment: @JamesMaynard, но с проблемой на сервере вам, скорее всего, придётся разбираться отдельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если перед вами не стоит какой-то глобальной неозвученной задачи, а требуется лишь получить количество отведённых файловых декскрипторов, то можно воспользоваться, например, содержимым псевдо-файала `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
2208    0   395478
```

[The three values in
file-nr denote the number of allocated file handles, the number
of allocated but unused file handles, and the maximum number of
file handles.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)

мой вольный перевод: первое число — количество отведённых файловых дескрипторов, второе — количество отведённых, но не используемых файловых дескрипторов, третье — максимальное количество файловых дескрипторов.

Comment: Мне этот вариант не подходит. Мне нужно узнать количество открытых файлов, как делает это lsof.

Comment: а в чём вы видите разницу между «открытым файлом» и «отведённым файловым дескриптором»?

Comment: Каюсь был не прав. Подскажите как вывести только первое значение в файл. Тоесть я хочу получать при запросе не три значения а одно. Пологаю нужно делать cut значения. Подскажите как.

Comment: если хотите с помощью `cut`, то, например, так: `$ cut -f 1 /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - выводить количество строк lsof в файл заданием cron, к примеру, раз в минуту делать:

```
# lsof | wc -l > /tmp/openfiles
```

И дёргать их оттуда заббиксом через cat.
Плюсы такого подхода - можно получать количество открытых файлов для юзера, типа:

```
# lsof | grep oracle | wc -l > /tmp/openfiles.userOracle
```